# get the length of a query in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to get the length of a query and return the length and full query, like this:

```
  {
  "total": 73,
  "votes": [
    { some fields.. },
    { some fields.. },
  ]
  }
```

my solution is:

```
const votes = await VotesModel.find();
const total = votes.length;

return {total, votes}
```

but the question is, can I get the same result in a simple query?

or what would be the correct way to return the length and the query?

Answer (score 0):

You need call .toArray() function.

```js
const votes = await VotesModel.find().toArray();
const total = votes.length;

return {total, votes}
```